# WCF Service hosted in IIS6 gets 404 in Production

Tags: wcf, iis-6, load-balancing

I have built a simple WCF Service and deployed it to IIS6, and I'm noticing that it works in my Dev and Staging environments, but not Production.  Every time I try to hit the service metadata link, I get a 404 page.

I've checked IIS config everywhere I can think of and they're identical, so the only difference I can think of is that the Production environment is load balanced.

Does anyone know of any issues with running a WCF service behind a load balancer, and how can I get around that?  Am I on the wrong track, is there another common problem I should look into?

Answer (score 5):

You need to setup wild card mapping on IIS6. This [link](http://peterkellner.net/2008/08/24/urlrewrite-with-aspnet-urlrewriter-wildcard-mapping-iis6-iis7/) seems like a good step by step guide.

Try reading up on the differences between the integrated pipeline vs classic pipeline on IIS7

Comment: The .svc extension needs to be mapped to the aspnet.dll. This is not always the case, even when .aspx-files are registered.

Answer (score 0):

For me .svc was already mapped to the aspnet_isapi.dll as per AnthonyWJones answer:

[image]

[image]

I kept getting 404's and nothing in the logs (C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles\W3SVC1) helped, all my WCF settings and web.config were textbook examples. I triple checked all the permissions...

What my problem turned out to be was that I had built my WCF service in .Net 4.0, after I installed ASP.net 4.0 using `aspnet_regiis -i -enable` it worked straight away:

[image]