# WCF Syndication Service not found in II6

Tags: wcf, iis, rest, iis-6, syndication

I have a WCF Syndication Service that works fine when run locally on Windows Vista or Windows 7, but when it is deployed to a Windows 2003 Server, it gets a 404 (Resource cannot be found).

Non-REST WCF services work fine on this machine, so I know that .Net 3.5 is registered correctly in IIS.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a Microsoft contact, we discovered the solution to this problem.  Though .Net  Syndication is part of WCF, it is part of .Net 3.5, not 3.0.  The 2003 server had 3.0 installed which is the reason why the other WCF services present on the machine were functional, but did not have .Net 3.5 installed.  Installing .Net 3.5 SP1 resolved our issue.  Thank you Darrel Miller for responding with that piece of insight.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue has been raised many times before.  Search for IIS WCF 404, or checkout this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341438/wcf-service-hosted-in-iis6-gets-404-in-production).